# Is it possible to 'fork a fork' in Github?

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch

I am currently working on a project that is a spinoff (fork) from a framework I have been working on.

This project is intended to be pretty generic, but now I need to fork the codebase again for a client of mine.

At this moment, I have created a custom branch for my client, but I'd rather have a standalone repository for this.

- **Is is possible to 'fork a fork'?**
- **If not, what alternatives do I have?**

**Outline of the situation:**

- Framework repository (original)

  - Generic application repository (fork)

    - *(not yet)* Client repository (fork of application)

**Note:** when trying to  'fork a fork' in Github, you will receive a notification that you have already forked the project:

[image: Image showing a forked project cannot be forked again]

Comment: I don't see why it should not be possible... have you tried it?

Comment: @Felix ah, perhaps I should have clarified that. It is not possible. Updated post to reflect this.

Comment: Oh ok ( :( ). Is it important that the project is also known to GitHub as a fork (maybe because of pull requests..)? Otherwise you might be able to clone their "real" repository and add it as GitHub project later...

Comment: @Felix I thought of that. Could be a possible alternative, yeah. I'd still prefer the entire fork history to be preserved, though.

Comment: I see... in any way, I suggest to contact GitHub support (if you haven't done so yet).

Comment: Ahh... it seems your problem is a different one. Do you want to create a fork of your own project? Or do you want to create a second fork from a project? (Because forking a fork in general is possible).

Comment: I don't know it will be a correct alternatives, because it's depend on your framework. If your generic application not modifying your framework, your framework should be a submodule of your application instead of forking/cloning it. With submodule-ing it, you are keeping the project separated, but still the same.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you considered putting the forked fork simply into branches with a `forke2/` prefix?

Comment: I have the same problem I already fork the main project., But now there is a fork of the main project (by another user) with a branch that i want to use and if I try to fork from this branch/fork it just takes me to my original fork of the main project.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I contacted GitHub support about this 'issue' and they confirmed this is not possible. Also, it is very unlikely that such a feature will be implemented in the future.

Comment: We have a  solid scenario where this feature is *required*.  In 2015: Is Github still insistent on not supporting this use case?

Comment: This is now very possible. You just go to the fork you want to fork and click "fork" like you would always do. This only works if you don't have a different fork of that repository in your account already, though. If you do, you have to delete it. Here's an example: https://github.com/tmk/tmk_keyboard/network/members

Comment: They ought to support having both a fork of the original repo and a fork of a fork, simultaneously. They only need to keep track of the parent repo id for it to work.

Comment: It's still not possible, two years later. I've been running into the same issue, today. In my case the original project is dead, so it's ok to create a clone of the original project that I still need for maintenance. But what if I wanted to contribute to two forks of the same project?

Comment: Same issue. This is very questionable design at best and doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: After 3 years it still is not possible. Renaming a forked repo won't help either.

Answer (score 50):

> This is now very possible. You just go to the fork you want to fork
>   and click "fork" like you would always do. This only works if you
>   don't have a different fork of that repository in your account
>   already, though. If you do, you have to delete it.

Answered in a comment by [iFreilicht](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675994/is-it-possible-to-fork-a-fork-in-github#comment65238299_6896839)

Since this is the correct answer now, it is better to highlight it.

Comment: This is not a correct answer, since the person doesn't want to delete his original repository someone made a fork of, he/she now wants again to fork with their modifications.

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer: Yes and no.

No, for a single account as you are unable to create two repositories with the same name (and forks always have the same name).

Yes, for multiple accounts. So you could setup an organization for your second fork.

Comment: @Korakter that seems to be the problem: the original project is personal, the fork is organizational. The third one *should* be organizational...

Comment: Don't see a problem: As long as the second and third repo goes into different organizations, it works.

Comment: That still is the problem though; I'd rather not create another organization account for this, since it is technically still the same organization, and these are paid accounts.

Comment: You should use branches then, not forks.

Comment: @Koraktor: "unable to create two repositories with the same name (and forks always have the same name)." Couldn't you rename the repository in Admin > Settings > Repository Name?

Comment: "forks always have the same name" - so this should work if you rename the first fork. But renaming (as suggested by @XP1) does not seem to be enough to create a new fork.

Answer (score 1):

I use branches to track different forks. I use Github mainly as an online version of my local repositories to share with others. So my use case may not be what you want. However, I'll outline how I do it in case some find it useful.

TL;DR: Following is an example of a codebase that tracks both the synergy-core and barrier which are both forks of the same repository.

I have different remotes for the forks.

```
$ git remote -v
barrier gh:debauchee/barrier.git (fetch)
barrier gh:debauchee/barrier.git (push)
synergy gh:symless/synergy-core.git (fetch)
synergy gh:symless/synergy-core.git (push)
```

gh is simply a shortcut in the .ssh/config for github

Then I have branches that track the different forks based on the remote names.

```
$ git branch -vv
  barrier 653e4bad [barrier/master] Merge pull request #1067 from cryzed/fix/server-preserve-focus
* master  653e4bad [origin/master] Merge pull request #1067 from cryzed/fix/server-preserve-focus
  synergy cfe20bea [synergy/master] Change error priority based on param (#7279)
```

I can now pull all the changes and keep them updated. I can push the branches to Github and let people access the tracked forks by switching branches in my repository.

Answer (score 0):

now,there is a drop-down arrow, you can chose base repository
[image: drop-down arrow]

Comment: could you elaborate on where to find this?

Comment: yes, please elaborate, the attachment you added is not visible