# How to check whether I have a fork of a given GitHub repo?

Tags: github, github-api

Let's say there is a repository `foo/bar` which I forked to `me/custom-bar`. How do I check programmatically (API call maybe?) given `foo/bar` that there exists a fork that I own from this upstream? Currently, GitHub has the `repos/owner/id/forks` API endpoint that returns upto 100 entries if you explicitly mention it. I don't see any parameters for creating a custom query for this particular problem. Counting in the rate-limiting and stuff, I don't think it's possible to know this using this API endpoint if I had say a fork of the linux project where over 20k+ forks exist. Is there any fast and efficient way to know this?

**Note:** I don't want to use authentication if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New option (June 2022), directly on GitHub (instead of locally through API)

> ### [The repository fork button now displays existing forks](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-29-the-repository-fork-button-now-displays-existing-forks/)
>
> A dropdown has been added to the Fork button to help you quickly find your forks of a repository. This includes forks in your personal account and in organizations that you're a member of.
>
> [image: Example of the "your existing forks" dropdown -- https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/771134/175119425-5ca5d020-7acb-4f1a-84bf-272980717f78.png?ssl=1]
>
> This feature was inspired by **[Refined GitHub](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github)** – an impressive open source project maintained by [`@fregante`](https://github.com/sponsors/fregante).
> The feature was requested of GitHub through the [GitHub Stars program](https://stars.github.com/).
>
> Read more about [forking a repository](https://docs.github.com/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo) in the GitHub documentation.
>
> We appreciate feedback on this and other topics in GitHub's [public feedback discussions](https://github.com/orgs/github-community/discussions/categories/general).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround... you can always try to fork your own repo ([`POST /repos/:owner/:repo/forks`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork)).

As explained in "[Is it possible to 'fork a fork' in Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6896839/6309)", that won't be generally possible (for a sigle non-organization account) to do if your own repo is itself a fork.

Comment: I have two questions about this — 1. Wouldn't it unnecessarily create a new fork if I don't have one? 2. This is not possible w/o authentication which I don't want to do (I'll edit my query)

Comment: 1/ yes, you would need to delete it ;) 2/ yes, you need authentication: as I said, it is a *workaround*...

Comment: Hm... your workaround _works_ but I really want a non-invasive method of doing this. I wish the API allowed passing in some search options.

Comment: @SangeethSudheer I understand, and looked for such an API, but did not find one.

Comment: @SangeethSudheer That being said, https://developer.github.com/v4/ might help crafting a more precise query without the pagination issue.

Comment: :( Oh, I'll look into that and see if it's possible. Thanks for the suggestions so far.

Answer (score 0):

A solution here will be:

1. Check your repositories using `GET /users/:username/repos`
2. For each repo which `fork` property is true, GEt repository information using `GET /repos/:owner/:repo`
3. Check the parent object in json response (that contains parent folder of fork) and validate if `full_name` is your `foo/bar` repo