# Cannot send a commit to a forked repo vía API

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

Is there a way to send commits vía API to a pull request made from a not own forked repo.

I can send commits to my own repo.

Sometimes i want to make some changes on a pull request made for other person and the only thing i think is send commits in its forked repo. But the API throws me "Not Found".

Here is the code in curl

```
curl.exe -i -X PUT -H "Authorization: token TOKEN" -d "{\"message\":\"update\", \"content\": \"SG9sYSBtdW5kaWxsbwo=\",  \"branch\" : \"BRANCH\",  \"sha\" : \"SHA\"}" "https://api.github.com/repos/otherPerson/MyRepo/contents/File"
```

EDIT: I can push commits to the forked repo vía Github front-end , on the web.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> But the API throws me "Not Found".

This means you are not a [collaborator on that repo](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/wiki/Collaborating%3A-git-development-workflow), which implies you cannot directly push commits.

Since you [cannot fork a fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6896839/6309), you could [create a patch](https://nithinbekal.com/posts/git-patch/), publish it as a workaround to a gist, and leave a comment to the fork PR in progress to [apply that patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2250170/6309).

Comment: Hi VonC, the strangest thing is that i can send commits vía Github front-end directly to the forked repository. At least to the head branch

Comment: @lsalvatore That is strange: maybe GitHub support would have more on this: https://github.com/contact